# Have it ever happened to you, when you type fast, e.g "kill", it turns out "ikll"?

Tags: keyboard, input, input-device, keystrokes

I have bought a new keyboard and noticed this glitch so many times now.

Whenever you type some two keys in a very quick succession, there is a chance that the OS will interpret those keys backwards? Like, when I quickly type "wq", it sometimes inputs as "qw" and I'm not mistaken, I measure my fingers very precisely :)

Could it be re**al**ted to the default USB-keyboard refresh rate? How can one increase it without any specialized software from vendor (because there is none)?

Comment: Voting to reopen because the cause of the problem linked in the target is different. That question likely involves the cursor being moved while typing, while this is about transposition of keys on the keyboard itself. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/182894/why-would-a-computer-swap-letters-around-when-typing-very-fast/1079662#1079662) for a better understanding of this issue.

Comment: @bwDraco: Well, color me confused.  The boilerplate says, "This question already has an answer here:" (at the [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/182894/why-would-a-computer-switch-letters-around-when-typing-very-fast)).  If this question has an answer (two, counting [jtreser's](http://superuser.com/a/182949/150988)) at the other question, why should we reopen this one?

Comment: @Scott because there is no **real** answer to exactly this question over there. Except for `bwDraco`'s now.

Comment: @bwdraco - It looks like you put your answer in the wrong question ... and I'm not convinced it doesn't also answer the other question.

Comment: Where does the question http://superuser.com/questions/182894/why-would-a-computer-swap-letters-around-when-typing-very-fast itself mention mouse cursor being related to the issue?

Comment: Indeed, @bwDraco, like random suggested: one of the *answers* may not apply (and none was accepted), but the *question* is simply a duplicate. (It even seems to me your answer there overlaps the highest voted answer?)