# How could one increase the USB keyboard refresh rate from default 125Hz to, say, 1000Hz?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, keyboard, refresh-rate

I have asked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1079658/have-it-ever-happened-to-you-when-you-type-fast-e-g-kill-it-turns-out-ikll) question before and here what I came up with:

How could one increase the USB keyboard refresh rate? I need it for my keyboard to stop swapping quickly pressed keys. I'm running Windows 10.

EDIT:

It's not a duplicate, as I ask 'how to increase refresh rate?' and not 'oh, should I buy a new keyboard may be?'

Comment: "while consumer-grade keyboards generally poll at only 125 Hz, which can easily cause problems when typing fast, **gaming keyboards typically poll at 1000 Hz**, which is much less likely to result in erroneous registration." from [Why would a computer swap letters around when typing very fast?](http://superuser.com/a/1079662)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would a computer swap letters around when typing very fast?](http://superuser.com/questions/182894/why-would-a-computer-swap-letters-around-when-typing-very-fast)

Comment: @DavidPostill have you even read the title?

Comment: Yes. Of course I read the question. The polling rate is determined by the keyboard not by the OS. That's why **some** keyboards (normally gaming keyboards) have a **physical switch** to change the polling rate.

Comment: @DavidPostill so, returning to my question. Is there a way to change it for my non-gaming keyboard?

Comment: Not unless your non-gaming keyboard has a physical switch or is programmable to do so by software in the keyboard.

Comment: Well, may be there is a way to get some 3rd party driver that would do the trick?

Comment: It's nothing to do with drivers. It is set by **hardware** in the keyboard (the switch) or  by **software** provided by the keyboard vendor that talks to the **hardware** in the keyboard. If the **hardware** isn't there nothing can change it :p

Comment: @DavidPostill well, [this](http://forums.atomicmpc.com.au/index.php/topic/55924-how-to-change-polling-rate-of-usb-keyboard/) page claims to have an answer. It is just outdated and not working anymore. Which means, there **are** ways.

Comment: <shrug> You can write your own answer saying it is possible but not working then ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill I would like to donate some of my rep for a good answer instead.

Comment: http://www.ngohq.com/news/15043-how-to-increase-usb-sample-rate-in-windows-vista-7-a.html

Comment: You can increase the polling rate of the port, not the keyboard.

Comment: @JamieWilletts already did it - it says everything is fine, enjoy, but the keys are still swapped.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot increase it beyond the manufacturers parameters.

Get a good gaming KB, and it will allow you to set it even up to 1000, but those were designed to support values that high. The manufacturers driver will allow you to set various values usually between 100 and 1000.